# Qt is not showing QML window properly

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qmainwindow

I can change size of a mainwindow. When application starts I first see mainwindow for 2 sec and then it load QML file inside. Problem is that whenever I try to change size of QML file it is always same size. I have tried everything. I want to be able to change size so I can see what size works best for my needs.

I think problem is in this part of code, but as I said I don't know how to handle it.

Here is my code:

```
QDeclarativeView *view= new QDeclarativeView;
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setCentralWidget(view);

    QDeclarativeContext *ctxt = view->rootContext();
    ctxt->setContextProperty("funkcije",this);
    ctxt->setContextProperty("myModel", QVariant::fromValue(MainWindow::dataList));


     view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/gui.qml"));
     view->setResizeMode(QDeclarativeView::SizeRootObjectToView);
```

Because when I put in main.cpp something like `mainwindow.showMaximized();` I can see that mainwindow is changing sizes but then it loads qml and it is always same size whenever I change qml or qt code.

Answer (score 0):

Try call setResizeMode first:

```
 view->setResizeMode(QDeclarativeView::SizeRootObjectToView);
 view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/gui.qml"));
```

I have no clear idea why this works, but that did the trick from me once.

Good Luck !